# Taking the values of a specific list

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the code of a web page contains this:

```
<script>
ara.bar.addData({"name":"page1","mylist":{"1":2,"2":2,"3":2,"4":2}});
</script>
```

How can I retrieve an object with the keys/values from mylist?

Comment: You can't unless the `ara` construct exposes methods to let you get at the values set on it. If you're asking how you access that object if it was in its own variable, then it would be `variable.name.page1.mylist`.

Comment: wouldn't it be just `variable.mylist`?

Comment: *"How can I retrieve an object with the keys/values from mylist?"* Where? When? Inside `addData`? In your code *calling* `addData`?

Comment: You must look into the `addData` code, and see what it does with the parameter you're passing, and then, see if it's possible to get it back.

Comment: I'm assuming from the question that OP doesn't own the code. The code is on a website outside of his control.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a **very** active place. When you ask a question, *stick around* for a few minutes to answer people asking for clarification so they can help you.

Comment: @eabcde, is this your code, or code on a random website you don't own?

Answer (score 1):

You've said below you want to use that data *in* the `addData` code. You just use whatever name you gave the argument (I'll call it `options` below, but the name doesn't matter) and access its `mylist` property. The object referenced by `mylist` as properties called `1`, `2`, and so on. Because those names start with a digit, you have to use brackets notation to access those:

```
function addData(options) {
    console.log(options.mylist[1]);   // 2
}
```

You can either use `"1"` or `1` (and `"2"` and `2`, etc.) when accessing `mylist`'s properties; technically the name is a string, so if you use `1`, it'll get coerced to a string.

That said, I wouldn't make `mylist` a raw object, I'd make it an *array* so that it has `length` and so that writing is is more compact:

```
ara.bar.addData({"name":"page1","mylist":[2,2,2,2]});
```

Then your `options.mylist` would be an array with properties `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3` (all of which have the value `2` in your example).

Comment: TJ, it's not clear from the question that the OP actually has access to the code, or whether he's found a site with the code on it and wants to access the object somehow.

Comment: @Andy: That's why I listed both options. But the question needs clarification, no...um...question about that. :-)

Comment: @eabcde: No, because you're passing that object *into* your function as an argument. So you give it whatever name you want (I just used `options` as an example), and then access the properties on it as `argumentName.name`, `argumentName.mylist`, etc.